# vim editor full screen in putty

Tags: linux, ssh, vim, putty, text-editors

I am using putty to connect to my linux server and if I open any files with vim or vi  editor the editor margins are getting limited, whereas the same full screen is coming if I open in XTERM. My desktop screen is having 1280 X 1024.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have `:set lines=N columns=M` commands that do the resizing. Unfortunately, not all terminals support the dynamic resizing. Apparently, PuTTY doesn't. I also tried

```
$ stty columns 120
```

directly in the terminal, also with no effect.

With PuTTY, you can work around this by manually putting its window to fullscreen (e.g. by double-clicking on the titlebar).

Comment: Yes , I already used set lines & columns but it is not giving properly some times. I was looking if there is any vim configuration which can be used. Because each and every time setting that option may become difficult.

Comment: After removing `set lines=68` from my .vimrc, no problem anymore with the display in PuTTY.